# Qt based program linked in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008

I'm writing a Qt based project using Visual Studio 2008 Compiler . In the debug mode every thing is OK and the program compiled and linked successfully but when I switch to release mode and I start to compile I get this error during linking :

```
1>Linking...
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>release\\MobnaPC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

But main function has defined!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use qmake? Then add your .pro file.